# How to check if the Form object is till running with C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say, I have 2 WinForms here, Form1 and Form2 respectively. And then I made Form1 hidden. I wonder how I could write the code in Form2 to detect if Form1 object is still running or not.

I was trying to use `Form1.ActiveForm` but it seems to give me NULL value. Any better ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you have hidden Form1, it automatically means that it is running but invisible.

Comment: I think you will have to use `form1.Show()`

Comment: So something like this: `Form1 form1 = new Form1(); form1.Show();` ?

Comment: But that means we are creating a new Form1 object, aren't we? How can I just restrict it to a single Form1 object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my method to get any active forms:

```
public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
{
   foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
   {
      if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
         return OpenForm;
   }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was good. didn't think about using `System.Windows.Form.Application.OpenForms` and give it a loop-through. Thanks for the tip, Vijay.

Comment: No problem.  If you need anything else just give me a shout! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are trying to access Form1 as a static instance and unless you have created Form1 in this manner you will not be able to access it and this could be why you are getting NULL values from your function. If you want to reference Form1 from Form2 then you need to pass it a reference.

Form1:

```
public class Form1
{
   public Form1()
   {
   }    
}
```

Form2:

```
public class Form2
{
   private Form1 _frm1;

   public Form2(Form1 frm1)
   {
       _frm1 = frm1;
   }
}
```

Now when you create your instance of Form2 you declare it like...

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(frm1);
```

Where frm1 is the instance of Form1.

Now whenever you need to refer to Form1 from Form2 you can refer to it via _frm1.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by running "is still in memory" then you could

- simply test the reference to the form: `if(form1 != null)`
- after that you could test for being hidden: `if(form1.Visible)`
- and possibly minimized: `if(form1.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether your form has been closed (and therefore disposed) you can try calling a method from that form and catching the `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
try 
{ 
    Form1.SomeMethod();
} 
catch (ObjectDisposedException ex) 
{ 
    // Form has been closed
}
```

If the form hasn't been closed, and you want to check whether it's visible or not, you can use it's ["Visible" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private Form GetForm()
        {
            Form mdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            Form1 objForm
            foreach (Form frm in mdiParent.MdiChildren)
            {
                objForm = frm as Form1;
                if (objForm != null)
                {

                   objForm.Activate();
                   return objForm;

                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a one-liner:

```
bool form1Exists = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Any();
```

or using the generic method:

```
private bool FormExists<T>() where T : Form
{
    return Application.OpenForms.OfType<T>().Any();
}
```

To use:

```
bool form1Exists = FormExists<Form1>();
```

Note that `Application.OpenForms` property gets a collection of open forms owned by the application **regardless of whether they are shown or hidden**.
And don't forget to add the following `using` to use the `OfType<T>` method:

```
using System.Linq;
```